# Android- Textview getting disappeared on drag operation

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, textview

I am creating one image editing application. In which I am giving facility to open camera or gallery to select picture. On selection of picture, user will navigate to other page. In other page to show picture I am using one view which implements `AppCompactImageView`. Now on it, I am giving facility to add text by using edittext. On click of "Done" button of soft keyboard, edittext will get disappeared and will get replaced by `TextView`. Now I want to drag this TextView all over the layout. But after drop operation, it's getting disappeared. Below is my code. Any help will be appreciable.

1. DrawActivity.java

   `public class DrawActivity extends AppCompatActivity {`

   ```
   DrawView imgView;
   Button resetBtn, saveBtn;
   ImageButton undoBtn;
   Bundle extras;
   Context context;
   EditText addTxtBox;
   ImageView brushImg, fontImg;
   TextView addedTxtView;
   // LinearLayout mainLinear;
   RelativeLayout mainRelative;
   public int rowX, rowY;
   public String txtVal;
   private android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       getSupportActionBar().hide();
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_draw);

       context = this.getApplicationContext();

       mainRelative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
       imgView = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.frag_home_iv_main);
       resetBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearBtn);
       undoBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.undoBtn);
       saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
       addTxtBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addTxt);
       brushImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageBrush);
       fontImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageFont);

       addedTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drawTextView);
       addedTxtView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
               ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)v.getTag());
               String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};

               ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(),mimeTypes, item);
               View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(addedTxtView);
               if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                   Log.d("Vishal sdk","in if");
                   v.startDragAndDrop(dragData, myShadow, null, 0);
               } else {
                   Log.d("Vishal sdk","in else");
                   v.startDrag(dragData, myShadow, null, 0);
               }
               return false;
           }
       });


       addedTxtView.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
               Log.d("Vishal check", String.valueOf(event.getAction()));
               switch(event.getAction()) {
                   case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                       layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
                       Log.d("Vishal Drag", "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");
                       return true;
                       // Do nothing

                   case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                       Log.d("Vishal Drag", "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
                       int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                       int y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                       return true;

                   case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
                       Log.d("Vishal Drag", "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                       x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                       y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                       layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
                       layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;
                       v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                       v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       // view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       return true;

                   case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
                       Log.d("Vishal Drag", "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");
                       x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                       y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                       return true;

                   case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :
                       Log.d("Vishal Drag", "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");
                       return true;
                       // Do nothing

                   case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                       Log.d("Vishal Drag", "ACTION_DROP event");
                      /* x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                       y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                       View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                       view.setX(x_cord - (view.getWidth() / 2));
                       view.setY(y_cord - (view.getWidth() / 2));
                       view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/

                       return true;
                       // Do nothing
                   default:
                       return true;

               }
               //return true;
           }
       });


       addTxtBox.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
       addTxtBox.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

       addTxtBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       // addedTxtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


       extras = getIntent().getExtras();
       imgView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(extras.getString("selectedImg")));

       imgView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

       brushImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               imgView.setBrushActive(true);
           }
       });

       fontImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               imgView.setBrushActive(false);
               addTxtBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               addTxtBox.requestFocus();
               InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
               imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
           }
       });

       addTxtBox.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
               if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                   Toast.makeText(DrawActivity.this, addTxtBox.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   addedTxtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   txtVal = addTxtBox.getText().toString();
                   imgView.getTxtValue(addTxtBox.getText().toString());
                   addedTxtView.setText(addTxtBox.getText().toString());
                   addedTxtView.setTag(addTxtBox.getText().toString());
                   addTxtBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   try {
                       InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                       inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(addTxtBox.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
                   }catch (Exception e){
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   return true;
               }
               return false;
           }
       });


       resetBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               imgView.resetPaths();
           }
       });

       undoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               imgView.removeLastPath();
           }
       });

       saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Bitmap bitmap = imgView.getDrawingCache();
               File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
               path.mkdirs();
               Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
               String ts = tsLong.toString();
               File imageFile = new File(path, ts+".png"); // Imagename.png

               try{
                   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // Compress Image
                   try {
                       out.flush();
                       out.close();
                   } catch (IOException e){
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }


                   // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
                   // immediately available to the user.
                   MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,new String[] { imageFile.getAbsolutePath() }, null,new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                       public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                           Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                           Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);

                       }
                   });
                   Toast.makeText(context,"Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   Intent intent = new Intent(DrawActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
               } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                   Toast.makeText(context,"Error" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       });

   }



   public void redrawImage() {
       Bitmap bm = imgView.getDrawingCache();
       Bitmap proxy = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
       Canvas c = new Canvas(proxy);
       Paint paint = new Paint();
       // paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
       paint.setColor(Color.RED);
       paint.setTextSize(100);
       paint.setAntiAlias(true);

       c.drawBitmap(bm, new Matrix(), paint);
       c.drawText(txtVal, imgView.getWidth()+rowX, imgView.getHeight()+rowY, paint);
       imgView.setImageBitmap(proxy);
   }

   public void changeColor(View view) {
       Log.d("Vishal selected color", view.getTag().toString());

       switch (view.getTag().toString()){
           case "red":
               imgView.setBrushColor(Color.RED);
               break;

           case "blue":
               imgView.setBrushColor(Color.BLUE);
               break;

           case "green" :
               imgView.setBrushColor(Color.GREEN);
               break;

           case "yellow":
               imgView.setBrushColor(Color.YELLOW);
               break;

           case "purple":
               imgView.setBrushColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
               break;

           default:
               imgView.setBrushColor(Color.BLACK);
       }
       //
   }
   ```

   }
2. activity_draw.xml

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@android:color/black" >

       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/undoBtn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:src="@drawable/undo"/>

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Clear"
           android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/saveBtn"/>

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Save"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

   </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1.8"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:id="@+id/draw_image_linearView">

       <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <com.example.mobilesolution.imgedit.DrawView
               android:id="@+id/frag_home_iv_main"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:adjustViewBounds="true"
               android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/drawTextView"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:elevation="100dp"
               android:layout_centerInParent="true"
               android:textColor="@android:color/black"
               android:textSize="16dp"
               />

           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/addTxt"
               android:layout_centerInParent="true"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:hint="Enter some text"
               android:inputType="textMultiLine"
               android:maxLines="3"
               android:elevation="10dp"/>


       </RelativeLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>

   <HorizontalScrollView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:fillViewport="true"
       android:paddingLeft="5dp"
       android:paddingRight="5dp"
       android:paddingTop="5dp"
       android:scrollbars="none"
       android:layout_weight="0.2">

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical">

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="447dp"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:padding="10dp">

               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/redBall"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                   android:onClick="changeColor"
                   android:src="@drawable/red_ball"
                   android:tag="red" />

               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/blueBall"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                   android:onClick="changeColor"
                   android:src="@drawable/blue_ball"
                   android:tag="blue" />

               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/greenBall"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                   android:onClick="changeColor"
                   android:src="@drawable/green_ball"
                   android:tag="green" />

               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/yellowBall"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                   android:onClick="changeColor"
                   android:src="@drawable/yellow_ball"
                   android:tag="yellow" />

               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/purpleBall"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                   android:onClick="changeColor"
                   android:src="@drawable/purple_ball"
                   android:tag="purple" />

               <ImageView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/red_ball" />

               <ImageView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/red_ball" />

               <ImageView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/red_ball" />

               <ImageView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/green_ball" />

               <ImageView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/green_ball" />

           </LinearLayout>
       </LinearLayout>


   </HorizontalScrollView>


   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/brushBtnLayout"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:background="@android:color/black">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageBrush"
           android:layout_width="65dp"
           android:layout_height="37dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="66dp"
           android:layout_marginStart="66dp"
           android:background="@android:color/white"
           android:src="@drawable/brush"
           android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageFont"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageFont"
           android:layout_width="65dp"
           android:layout_height="37dp"
           android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="52dp"
           android:background="@android:color/white"
           android:src="@drawable/font" />

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to set the `X` and `Y` coordinates when the drag exists instead of setting the margin.

**Update Again**
 The drop view is where your textview is supposed to be dropped into. This should hold the drag listener

```
frag_home_iv_main.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {
                int action = dragEvent.getAction();
                View viewdrag = (View) dragEvent.getLocalState();
                if(action == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED){
                    //do something
                }
                else if(action == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED){
                    //do something

                    Log.d("Vishal Drag", "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                    x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    viewdrag .setY(y_cord);
                    viewdrag .setX(x_cord);
                }

                else if(action == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP){
                    //do something
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Let me try once

Comment: Sorry it didn't worked for me.. Now I am not able to drag view.

Comment: You;re doing the drag and drop wrong. The drag listener must not be set on the view which is also being dragged. I've updated my answer

Comment: The view calling the `OnDragListener` and the view calling `startDrag` mustn't be the same

Comment: Really sorry, but I didn't get you exactly. Can you please explain in code?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Where do you want to drag the `TextView` to? As in which view should be waiting for the drop

Comment: I tried your code.. still same issue.. not able to drag view

Comment: Where do you want to drag the textview to?

Comment: to DrawView imgView; This view I have created dynamically...

public class DrawView extends AppCompatImageView

Comment: Then you ought to make the `DrawView` wait for the drag. I've updated the answer again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177207/discussion-between-niza-siwale-and-androidonhigh).

Answer (score 2):

You're dragging and setting the drag listener on the same view for starters, usually the drag listener is another view not the one being moved to listen to the view being dragged movements in case its over it or entered it or exited, etc.
Here's what I think you should do:

**Edit 2:**

```
//TODO change the view that listens to the drag event to root view layout
RelativeLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.yourRootViewLayout) //Change this to your root layout
layout.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
   //I changed the view that listens to the dragging, 
  //not sure if that's the one you prefer but you can choose your own 
 //to listen to these events if it overlaps or not, etc.
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            Log.d("Vishal check", String.valueOf(event.getAction()));
            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
                    Log.d("Vishal Drag", "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");
                    return true;
                    // Do nothing

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    Log.d("Vishal Drag", "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
                    int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    int y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    return true;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
                    Log.d("Vishal Drag", "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                    // view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return true;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
                    Log.d("Vishal Drag", "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");
                    x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    return true;

          //I put the code that you had in exited in ended because that's what 
          //listens to when  the drag stops no matter where it is
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :
                    Log.d("Vishal Drag", "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");
                    x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    //TODO change the code below
                    View newView = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) newView.getParent();
                    owner.removeView(newView);
                    RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) v;
                    container.addView(newView);
                    newView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    newView.setX(x_cord);
                    newView.setY(y_cord);
                    return true;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    Log.d("Vishal Drag", "ACTION_DROP event");
                   /* x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    view.setX(x_cord - (view.getWidth() / 2));
                    view.setY(y_cord - (view.getWidth() / 2));
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/

                    return true;
                    // Do nothing
                default:
                    return true;

            }
            //return true;
        }
    });
```

Let me know what happens and I'll gladly help if there are more issues.

```
addedTxtView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)v.getTag());
            String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};
        ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(),mimeTypes, item);
        //I changed addedTxtView to the current view being clicked
        View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Log.d("Vishal sdk","in if");
            //TODO Edit added v instead of null
            v.startDragAndDrop(dragData, myShadow, v, 0);
        } else {
            Log.d("Vishal sdk","in else");
            //TODO Edit added v instead of null
            v.startDrag(dragData, myShadow, v, 0);
        }
        //Let addedTxtView be invisible so there aren't two views at the same time
        addedTxtView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return false;
    }
});
```

I also edited the upper part: in case Drag event ACTION_DRAG_ENDED I made addedTxtView visible again after drag ends.

**Edit 2: I added TODOs in comments where I changed the code.**

Comment: Hi Mr.O... Thanks a lot for your help.. I tried your code.. Now it's not disappearing.. but for initial drag its moving to left most corner.. afterwords not able to drag.. it's getting stuck at same position...

Comment: You also added the edited part under `case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:` where `addedTxtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` ?

Comment: So what happens now is when you long click the text view, the shadow appears and moves with your finger but when you remove your finger it disappears completely and you have to recreate the activity for the text view to reappear?

Comment: Alright I made changes again to both sections of the code. I put TODOs in comments. I didn't know what your root view group layout for the activity was but I assumed Relative Layout, you need to set the id for it where I wrote the todo. If it is not a Relative layout, you'll need to change a few variables from Relative Layout to whatever it is. Thank you for your patience, please give it a try again?

Comment: Sorry need to make a quick edit again. The edits are in the section under `case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177504/discussion-between-mr-o-and-androidonhigh).